# Can't find SDK settings on Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Since yesterday, i'm fighting with Android Studio because I can't create a basic Android Project Template. I realized that there is no SDK settings and I can't configure anything. I updated my version, I uninstalled and reinstalled with user's settings cleaned and... still the same !

I attached some screenshots

No SDK settings

[image]

No SDK settings either

[image]

Comment: In Android Studio open File->Settings->System Settings->Android SDK->Android SDK Location

Comment: Did you just see my screenshots ? :/

Comment: Like I said, there is no settings like I can see on internet

Comment: It's a global setting. If you want to create a new project, just click "Create New Project" and follow the instructions

Comment: Try Tools -> SDK Manager in Android Studio

Comment: Ok, but again, I can't install Android SDK anywhere and I have no option to create an Android Porject, netiher use a template. There is only Gradle, and when I use it, there is no way to set or install an SDK.

Comment: @Surbhi https://imgur.com/a/ZRBZBjZ

Comment: @DmitriyMiyai https://imgur.com/a/4qhJ9qZ

Comment: Ok.. then try one more thing, there must be errors in events or messages. Try looking there

Comment: There is no messages in th event logs and I see no sign of any kind of error anywhere. I never had this on any computer with this IDE, it's kind of scaring me !

Comment: Can u see the option Project Structure

Comment: I can. There is default conf of Android Api but there is still no way to manage SDK and choose them have no effect
https://imgur.com/a/SBRMXko

Comment: Can't manage in Platform Settings -> SDK's too

Comment: What do you see after clicking on SDK's?

Comment: This -> https://imgur.com/a/5fjW5yb

Comment: I will suggest you to uninstall android studio completly. As there may be some problem when you were installing android studio. When it asks you whether you want to import previous settings then click on No and proceed. It will setup your android studio along with android sdk

Comment: I'll try to clean whatever I find and try to reinstall it again
Thanks

Comment: Ok so I cleaned really everything named Android on the computer this time and I reinstalled. This time, it asked me if I wanted to download the SDK and some tools like the emulator. Thanks for the help ! I guess it will work now ! IntelliJ is really something... I hate it.

Answer (score 2):

find your sdk here.Copy and Paste this in SDK location path.
C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk

make sure to check on Show hidden folders inside your folder option Menu in control penal.

Answer (score 1):

Shirosamus there is a **button to go to SDK Manager** from the **top right corner** the **third button starting from the last**  is the button to SDK Manager

Else as said in the answer, you can additionally download SDK and copy paste your SDK to the position said and it might work out.

Comment: No, there was not. IntelliJ was somehow broken. Clean the computer of anything of Android and Android Studio resolved the problem somehow.

Comment: That was not a noob question like "I don't know how to check a menu", don't worry.

Comment: No that is not a noob question, I never said it.

Comment: Instead I also think if we can't find sdk it can make issue for project we are working upon.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.
The thing is that Android Studio (maybe IntelliJ) was broken and there was no way to set anything about the SDK, even the SDK manager. Uninstall it did nothing. Even re install it didn't propose me to manage the SDK.
I cleaned everything on my computer concerning Android and Android Studio. When I re installed it, it asked me at the end to install an SDK and I even had the choice to create a project from a template (that was not possible before).

I'm surprised nobody encountered my bug.
Thanks everybody, and no thanks for the negative points because people thought I was a noob ahah.